# Get only third and sixth column from command output of pdffonts

Tags: python, awk, sed, poppler

I am using poppler pdffonts to get fonts in a pdf document.
Below is the sample output

```
$ pdffonts "some.pdf"
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
TimesNewRoman                        TrueType          WinAnsi          no  no  no      36  0
TimesNewRoman,Bold                   TrueType          WinAnsi          no  no  no      38  0
EDMFMD+Symbol                        CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     41  0
Arial                                TrueType          WinAnsi          no  no  no      43  0
Arial,Bold                           TrueType          WinAnsi          no  no  no      16  0
```

Now I want to get only "encoding" and "uni" column values in the above output. But I am unable to get  because of inconsistent space in each row.

Tried methods(Python):

1) Split each line by space and join by space and then split, so that elements of indices 2 and 5 in the resulting list will give me required values for each line. This approach is failing because of spaces in row values.

Code sample:

```
for line in os.popen("pdffonts some.pdf").readlines():
    print ' '.join(line.split()).split()
```

output:

```
['name', 'type', 'encoding', 'emb', 'sub', 'uni', 'object', 'ID']
['------------------------------------', '-----------------', '----------------', '---', '---', '---', '---------']
['FMGLMO+MyriadPro-Bold', 'Type', '1C', 'Custom', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', '127', '0']
['FMGMMM+MyriadPro-Semibold', 'Type', '1C', 'Custom', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', '88', '0']
['Arial-BoldMT', 'TrueType', 'WinAnsi', 'no', 'no', 'no', '90', '0']
['TimesNewRomanPSMT', 'TrueType', 'WinAnsi', 'no', 'no', 'no', '92', '0']
['FMGMHL+TimesNewRomanPSMT', 'CID', 'TrueType', 'Identity-H', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', '95', '0']
['FMHBEE+Arial-BoldMT', 'CID', 'TrueType', 'Identity-H', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', '100', '0']
['TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT', 'TrueType', 'WinAnsi', 'no', 'no', 'no', '103', '0']
```

2) Use regex to split each line of the output with atleast two spaces. This approach is failing because now I cannot get index 5 is clubbed because only one space is present.

Code Sample:

```
for line in os.popen("pdffonts some.pdf").readlines():
    print re.split(r'\s{2,}', line.strip())
```

Output:

```
['name', 'type', 'encoding', 'emb sub uni object ID']
['------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------']
['FMGLMO+MyriadPro-Bold', 'Type 1C', 'Custom', 'yes yes yes', '127', '0']
['FMGMMM+MyriadPro-Semibold', 'Type 1C', 'Custom', 'yes yes yes', '88', '0']
['Arial-BoldMT', 'TrueType', 'WinAnsi', 'no', 'no', 'no', '90', '0']
['TimesNewRomanPSMT', 'TrueType', 'WinAnsi', 'no', 'no', 'no', '92', '0']
['FMGMHL+TimesNewRomanPSMT', 'CID TrueType', 'Identity-H', 'yes yes no', '95', '0']
['FMHBEE+Arial-BoldMT', 'CID TrueType', 'Identity-H', 'yes yes no', '100', '0']
['TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT', 'TrueType', 'WinAnsi', 'no', 'no', 'no', '103', '0']
```

AWK:
    Failing because of space issue.Please compare with original output to get the difference.

```
$ pdffonts "some.pdf"|awk '{print $3}'

encoding
----------------
WinAnsi
WinAnsi
TrueType
WinAnsi
WinAnsi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect string positions for every desired column:

```
with open('pdffonts.txt') as f:
    header =f.readline()
    read_data = f.read()
f.closed

header_values = header.split()

positions = {}
for name in header_values:
    positions[name] = header.index(name)
print(positions)
```

This will give you the following example dictinary:

```
{'name': 0, 'type': 37, 'encoding': 55, 'emb': 72, 'sub': 76, 'uni': 80, 'object': 84, 'ID': 91}
```

After that you can specify the substring range to extract:

```
desired_columns = []
for line in read_data.splitlines()[1:]:
    encoding = line[positions['encoding']:positions['emb']].strip()
    uni = line[positions['uni']:positions['object']].strip()
    desired_columns.append([encoding,uni])

print(desired_columns)
```

result:

```
[['WinAnsi', 'no'], ['WinAnsi', 'no'], ['Identity-H', 'yes'], ['WinAnsi', 'no'], ['WinAnsi', 'no']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk:

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='36 1:17 1:16 1:3 1:3 1:3 1:9' '{ print $3, $6 }' file
encoding         uni
---------------- ---
WinAnsi          no
WinAnsi          no
Identity-H       yes
WinAnsi          no
WinAnsi          no
```

---

From `man gawk`:

> **FIELDWIDTHS**
>
> A whitespace-separated list of field widths.  When set, gawk parses the input into fields of fixed width, instead of using the value of the FS variable as the field separator. Each field width may optionally be preceded by a colon-separated value specifying the number of characters to skip before the field starts...

Comment: FIELDWIDTHS option is only for gawk. I am getting wrong output if i am using awk. But with gawk it is working fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dashes below column names to determine where to cut line.

Conveniently we can find consecutive `"------"` in second row, and cut columns at the beginning and at the end of each dash sequence (starting with `" -"`, ending with `"- "`).

I wrote function `get_column`, which finds it based on column name.

```
import os

lines_in = os.popen("pdffonts some.pdf")
# read the column names
header = lines_in.readline();

# read the: --------...
column_dashes = lines_in.readline()

# find column starts and ends
column_starts = [0]
pos = 0
while True:
  pos = column_dashes.find(" -", pos)
  if pos == -1:
    break
  column_starts.append(pos+1)
  pos += 1

column_ends = []
pos = 0
while True:
  pos = column_dashes.find("- ", pos)
  if pos == -1:
    column_ends.append(len(column_dashes))
    break
  column_ends.append(pos+1)
  pos += 1

def get_column( line, name ):
  n = columns[name]
  return line[column_starts[n]:column_ends[n]].strip()

# get column names
columns = {}
for n in range(len(column_starts)):
  columns[ header[column_starts[n]:column_ends[n]].strip() ] = n

# read rest of the table
for line in lines_in.readlines():
  print( (get_column(line,"encoding"), get_column(line, "uni")) )
```

Result:

```
('WinAnsi', 'no')
('WinAnsi', 'no')
('Identity-H', 'yes')
('WinAnsi', 'no')
('WinAnsi', 'no')
```

Answer (score 0):

With Perl also, you could do it like below

```
> cat some.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
TimesNewRoman                        TrueType          WinAnsi          no  no  no      36  0
TimesNewRoman,Bold                   TrueType          WinAnsi          no  no  no      38  0
EDMFMD+Symbol                        CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     41  0
Arial                                TrueType          WinAnsi          no  no  no      43  0
Arial,Bold                           TrueType          WinAnsi          no  no  no      16  0
> perl -lane ' $enc=@F==9? $F[3]:$F[2]; print "$enc\t\t$F[-3]" ' some.pdf
encoding                uni
----------------                ---
WinAnsi         no
WinAnsi         no
Identity-H              yes
WinAnsi         no
WinAnsi         no
>
```